# How to define peerDependencies for private repository that uses tags for versioning?

Tags: npm, gitlab

I have a library of various assets, that I am sharing across multiple projects. This library is versioned by tags.

In my package.json I have defined it as peer dependency:

```
{
    peerDependencies: {
        "my-asset-library": git+https://git.my-company.com/my-asset-library.git#semver:^0.1.0
    }
}
```

However, when I run `npm install` in one of my projects, I get

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-project@1.1.43
npm ERR! Found: my-asset-library@0.1.30
npm ERR! node_modules/my-asset-library
npm ERR!   my-asset-library@"git+https://git.my-company.com/my-asset-library.git#semver:0.1.30" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer my-asset-library@"git+https://git.my-company.com/my-asset-library.git#semver:^0.1.0" from my-project@1.1.43
```

When I install the library using `npm i git+https://git.my-company.com/my-asset-library.git#0.1.30`, it works just fine.

It seems that the comparator for peerDependencies is not working correctly, but I don't know how to fix that.